# Read timeseries data from CSV

Tags: import, date-and-time, time-series, excel

I am new to Mathematica and have v10.
I would like to you use the new TimeSeriesAggregate[tsdata, "Quarter", Total] feature to return aggregated descriptive stats. I import a number of columns of returns data using import[,"CSV"] and the dates (first column) are being returned as "2010/12/12". I don't mind keeping this format but need the dates in the default format {yy,mm,dd..} for the TimeSeriesAggregate[[ function to work . COuld somebody tell me how I operate on the datalist to create or modify a column to get from an Excel Date format to a Mathematica date format. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you link to an example file?

Comment: Use [DateList](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateList.html), e.g., `DateList["2010/12/24"]` returns `{2010, 12, 24, 0, 0, 0.}`

Comment: Can do but how do I link a file to this conversation/post ?

Comment: Thanks Bob.  I can get that to work for the one-off date but it fails against my imported data for a) I have a header line which I would like to retain so I need to suppress that somehow and b) my date format remains unchanged after using DateLIst[] but might that be because if's in a dd/mm/yyyy format (i.e UK rather than US format) ?

Comment: actually here's some simple data                                                     Date,Price
16/05/2007,3655
16/06/2007,3435
16/07/2007,3528

Comment: You need an `@` before the person's name to have that person receive your comment unless it is the OP.  Note that `DateList[{"24/12/2010", {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}]` returns `{2010, 12, 24, 0, 0, 0.}` so: `data2 = MapAt[DateList[{#, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}] &, data, {2 ;;, 1}]`

Answer (score 2):

```
(data = {{Date, Price}, {"16/05/2007", 3655}, {"16/06/2007", 
     3435}, {"16/07/2007", 3528}}) // Grid
```

[image]

```
(data2 = MapAt[DateList[{#, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}] &, 
    data, {2 ;;, 1}]) // Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
rawData = {{"13/12/2010", 10}, {"15/12/2010", 20}, {"17/12/2010", 30},
   {"19/12/2010", 40}, {"21/12/2010", 50}, {"23/12/2010", 60},
   {"13/12/2011", 80}, {"15/12/2011", 70}, {"17/12/2011", 60},
   {"19/12/2011", 40}, {"21/12/2011", 50}, {"23/12/2011", 60},
   {"13/12/2012", 10}, {"15/12/2012", 20}, {"17/12/2012", 30},
   {"19/12/2012", 20}, {"21/12/2012", 10}, {"23/12/2012", 0}};

date = StringCases[rawData[[All, 1]], 
   x : DatePattern[{"Day", "Month", "Year"}] :> DateList[x]];
data = Partition[Riffle[Flatten[date, 1], rawData[[All, 2]]], 2]

DateListPlot[TimeSeriesAggregate[data, "Quarter"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if after you remove headers you have:

```
rawData = {{"13/12/2010", 10}, {"15/12/2010", 20}, {"17/12/2010", 
30}, {"19/12/2010", 40}, {"21/12/2010", 50}, {"23/12/2010", 
60}, {"13/12/2011", 80}, {"15/12/2011", 70}, {"17/12/2011", 
60}, {"19/12/2011", 40}, {"21/12/2011", 50}, {"23/12/2011", 
60}, {"13/12/2012", 10}, {"15/12/2012", 20}, {"17/12/2012", 
30}, {"19/12/2012", 20}, {"21/12/2012", 10}, {"23/12/2012", 0}};
```

Then applying TimeSeries directly will do the right thing:

```
In[45]:= ts = TimeSeries[rawData];

In[46]:= ts["Dates"]

Out[46]= {DateObject[{2010, 12, 13}], DateObject[{2010, 12, 15}], 
 DateObject[{2010, 12, 17}], DateObject[{2010, 12, 19}], 
 DateObject[{2010, 12, 21}], DateObject[{2010, 12, 23}], 
 DateObject[{2011, 12, 13}], DateObject[{2011, 12, 15}], 
 DateObject[{2011, 12, 17}], DateObject[{2011, 12, 19}], 
 DateObject[{2011, 12, 21}], DateObject[{2011, 12, 23}], 
 DateObject[{2012, 12, 13}], DateObject[{2012, 12, 15}], 
 DateObject[{2012, 12, 17}], DateObject[{2012, 12, 19}], 
 DateObject[{2012, 12, 21}], DateObject[{2012, 12, 23}]}
```

TimeSeriesAggregate will work with the resulting TimeSeries object:

```
In[51]:= TimeSeriesAggregate[ts, Quantity[3, "Days"], Total] // Normal

Out[51]= {{DateObject[{2010, 12, 14}, 
   TimeObject[{12, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -5.], TimeZone -> -5.], 
  30}, {DateObject[{2010, 12, 17}, 
   TimeObject[{12, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -5.], TimeZone -> -5.], 
  30}, {DateObject[{2010, 12, 20}, 
   TimeObject[{12, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -5.], TimeZone -> -5.], 
  90}, {DateObject[{2010, 12, 23}, 
   TimeObject[{12, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -5.], TimeZone -> -5.], 
  60}, {DateObject[{2011, 12, 12}, 
   TimeObject[{12, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -5.], TimeZone -> -5.], 
  80}, {DateObject[{2011, 12, 15}, 
   TimeObject[{12, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -5.], TimeZone -> -5.], 
  70}, {DateObject[{2011, 12, 18}, 
   TimeObject[{12, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -5.], TimeZone -> -5.], 
  100}, {DateObject[{2011, 12, 21}, 
   TimeObject[{12, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -5.], TimeZone -> -5.], 
  50}, {DateObject[{2011, 12, 24}, 
   TimeObject[{12, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -5.], TimeZone -> -5.], 
  60}, {DateObject[{2012, 12, 12}, 
   TimeObject[{12, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -5.], TimeZone -> -5.], 
  10}, {DateObject[{2012, 12, 15}, 
   TimeObject[{12, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -5.], TimeZone -> -5.], 
  20}, {DateObject[{2012, 12, 18}, 
   TimeObject[{12, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -5.], TimeZone -> -5.], 
  50}, {DateObject[{2012, 12, 21}, 
   TimeObject[{12, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -5.], TimeZone -> -5.], 
  10}, {DateObject[{2012, 12, 24}, 
   TimeObject[{12, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -5.], TimeZone -> -5.], 0}}
```